# Subtotal, Shipping, Discount and Grand Total Missing in Magento

Tags: magento, checkout, magento-1.4, subtotal

Hope someone can point me in the right direction. I am not a Magento developer but am having to fix my site after my "developer" left me with most of the work to do.

Currently in my checkout screen i'm not seeing any values other than that of the actual product item value - no subtotals, discounts, shipping or the grand total. They all appear ok on the emails that are sent though (luckily).

I'm not using the default Magento package but from what i can see all the .phtml files seem to be there in the base directories and are not in my new design directories - so i would have assumed all would work ok. But alas, no. Is there anywhere i should be looking/tweaking etc etc? Have googled about as much as i can but to no avail.

I'm sure it must be something simple (!?) if all appear on the emails ok. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: When you say you are not using default Magento package there must be at least some design files in your new design directories! Which design directories have you looked into until now or which ones do exist in your new design folder?

Comment: Hi Ozair, i looked in the directories where people say the code is - like app/design/frontend/template/checkout and app/design/frontend/template/tax/checkout - but to be honest i'm not sure what i'm looking for. I can see files that have the text in that should appear on the checkout, but its not appearing. I do have some new versions of the files in the template/checkout section, but the tax/checkout only appears in the base (original) directories.

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is fairly old now but just in case anyone else comes across this I had this problem and for me all I had to do some enable the Mage_Tax module in System > Configuration > Advanced

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question without more insight, but here is what can be a starting point:

1. Login to your shop's `admin panel`.
2. In `System` menu click on `Configuration`.
3. From the `Current Configuration Scope` box select your Website.
4. Now in the menu on left-hand side under `Configuration > Advanced` (almost to the bottom of the screen)
5. Click on `Developer`
6. Now in the main panel, click on `Debug`.
7. For the field `Template Path Hints` select `Yes`.
8. Now reload your website (front-end) and you will see from which template is each part of the page being loaded.

Also if Magento's cache is enabled, you will need to [clear that](http://alanstorm.com/magento_cache_clear). I would suggest that this cache be disabled during development and/or on non-production versions of your site.

Comment: hi Ozair, thanks for replying - i checked the template -its checkout/onepage/review/totals.phtml in my local design - but i checked code with base file and its identical - so code is there, but something somewhere is stopping it displaying - is there any config that i could check? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Fred: See if there are any differences between `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` and `app/design/frontend/default/<your_template>/layout/checkout.xml`